# Why are the following computations not equivalent?

Tags: combinatorics

Assume I have a circular table with $12$ seats, and I want to seat $6$ men and $6$ women such that all men sit sequentially and all women sit sequentially (So, all men are together in a row and all women are together in a row).

First attempt: Let one man sit in any seat. This decides the layout of the table (because the table is circular), now, there are $6$ ways to choose the seats where all other men will sit (because the man I chose at first can either be at the $2$ ends of the row of men or at the $4$ middle positions of the row), $5!$ ways to seat the $5$ remaining men, and $6!$ ways to seat the women. In total we get $6\cdot5!\cdot6!=6!\cdot6!$ possibilities.

Second attempt: From the $6$ men I can choose $12$ seats to sit in, from the remaining $5$ men I can choose $2$ seats to sit in (to the left or to the right of the first man), from the $4$ remaining men I can choose $2$ seats to sit in (to the right of the first two men or to the left) and so on, so I get $6\cdot12\cdot5\cdot2\cdot4\cdot2\cdot3\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot1\cdot2=6!\cdot12\cdot2^5$,
finally, there are $6!$ ways to seat the women, and the table is a circle so every rotation is a duplicate so I need to divide by $12$, so the final answer is $6!\cdot6!\cdot2^5$

The two answers I got are clearly different, which one is wrong, and why?

Comment: Your second approach overcounts because it can produce the same arrangement in different ways (choosing the men in different orders).

Comment: A simpler correct approach is to choose the clockwise order of the men (6! options) and the clockwise order of the women (6! options), which determines the arrangement up to rotations.

Comment: Amplifying the comment of @Karl, which I agree with, the $~6~$ men form 1 fused unit, and the $~6~$ women form a second fused unit.  So, you have two fused units to permute, and each fused unit allows $~6!~$ internal permutations.  This implies that if the layout was a row, instead of a circular table, then the computation would be $~2! \times 6! \times 6!.~$  ...see next comment

Comment: The typical adjustment from row to circular table would then be $$(2-1)! \times 6! \times 6!$$ which represents that once the people are seated in chairs along the table, the table itself can be rotated to put either fused unit at the head of the table.